# Union of all points of $\text{Spec}(R)$ being $R-R^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Every non unit element of $R$ belongs to a maximal ideal. Maximal ideals are prime ideals. So the prime ideals cover all the non unit elements of $R$. So the union of all the points of $\text{Spec}(R)$ is almost $R$. Or I am wrong, and this is all of $R$? It seems we always miss the trivial ideal, but this just is $R$.

Is there significance in the union of all points of $\text{Spec}(R)$ being $R-R^\times$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct: every non-unit belongs to a maximal ideal, but conversely a maximal ideal cannot contain a unit, so 
$$\bigcup_{\mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec}(R)} \mathfrak{p} = R - R^\times.$$
One related fact is that a basis of open sets for the topology of $\text{Spec}(R)$ is given by the open sets
$$D(f) = \{ \mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec}(R): f \notin \mathfrak{p} \}, \quad f \in R,$$
and $D(f)$ is "non-trivial" (by which I mean not equal to the whole space) precisely when $f \in R - R^\times$. (Though there is the other trivial case $D(0) = \emptyset.$) I'm not sure if there is additional significance to the union in question.